# ln: invalid option -- '/'

Tags: command-line, kernel, symbolic-link

I have a situation with `ln` and cannot solve this even after I've read about `ln` in help.

Running the following command:

```
ln -sf  /lib/modules/$kernel_version/extra/mISDN_core.ko /lib/modules/$kernel_version/kernel/drivers/isdn/mISDN/mISDN_core.ko
```

Provides the following error:

```
ln: invalid option -- '/'
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: what exactly did you try to do? what should be the meaning of `**.ko`?

Comment: hi. whole string is: ln -sf /lib/modules/$kernel_version/extra/mISDN_core.ko /lib/modules/$kernel_version/kernel/drivers/isdn/mISDN/mISDN_core.ko          and I am trying to configure network in a box

Comment: What is the idea of wildcards in your command? That will never work. You are supposed to change "#ker_ver" to the kernel you want this to do with and the same with the "**" That needs to be a name for a specific "ko".

Comment: Rinzwind, sorry for unclear example, I am going to fix it now

Comment: Have you assigned to the variable `$kernel_version`? If so, what is its value?

Comment: kernel_version = ‘uname -r‘

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to clarify something or add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd suggest replacing the `$kernel_version` variable with the actual value.

As described below, using the below command with *backtick* instead of *single quote* should solve the problem as well:

```
$ kernel_version=`uname -r`
```

---

As mentioned by @steeldriver the error seems to be due to use of *single quote* instead of *backtick* which surround the `uname -r` command.

hence the following sample command:

```
$ kernel_version='uname -r'
$ ln -sf /tmp/test/$kernel_version/example /tmp/newname
ln: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'ln --help' for more information.
```

Will be translated to:

```
$ ln -sf /tmp/test/uname -r/example /tmp/newname
ln: invalid option -- '/'
Try 'ln --help' for more information.
```

And as @steeldriver wrote: Presumably the error message is about **invalid option `'/'`** because `-r` is a valid option for the `ln` command

Note that using *backtick* would work without errors:

```
$ kernel_version=`uname -r`
$ ln -sf /tmp/test/$kernel_version/example /tmp/newname
$ 
$ ls -l /tmp/newname 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 35 Feb 21 16:02 /tmp/newname -> /tmp/test/4.4.0-112-generic/example
```

Comment: after replacing the '$kernel_version' with the actual name worked! thank you!

Comment: thank you Yaron for update, I've read about it, occasionally that didn't solve a problem, but true name of $kernel did.

Comment: just a simple question to the system, why error message doesn't describe the man problem? why it said invalid option - '/'?

Comment: @AlekseiKovaltsuk - Happy that your problem was solved!

Comment: @AlekseiKovaltsuk `ln` tries hard to find every option you enter, and as the content of the variable contains single hyphens `-`, “this must be options” it thinks. But before that, there's a path beginning with a slash `/`. “This must also be an option then because there are others behind it, but **stop**, I don't know an option beginning like that! Let's inform the user I found an invalid option and which character confuses me here.“ So `ln` says `:` There's an `invalid option`, find the strange thing in single quotes after the double hyphens so it's clear what character I mean: `-- '/'`.

Comment: @Yaron I don't think the issue is dashes in the uname *output* - it looks like the OP set `kernel_version` to the literal string `uname -r` (using single quotes) rather than the output of a command substitution (backticks). Presumably the error message is about option `/` because `-r` *is* a valid option for the `ln` command

Answer (score 0):

1. Use the `$( ... )` notation instead of the old-style backticks `` `...` `` for command substitution. It looks better, and nests better. And is less likely to be mixed up with quotes.
2. Quote your variables. With the string `uname -r` in `kernel_version`, `/lib/modules/$kernel_version/extra/mISDN_core.ko` expands to the two words `/lib/modules/uname` and `-r/extra/mISDN_core.ko`, when you clearly wanted only one filename.

   Quoted, `"/lib/modules/$kernel_version/extra/mISDN_core.ko"` would expand to `/lib/modules/uname -r/extra/mISDN_core.ko` as a single word, and you'd get an error from `ln` because a file by that name does not exist.
3. Not exactly necessary here if you quoted the variables properly, since your filenames start with a slash, but in general you may want to consider adding the double-dash `--` to signal the end of options. With filenames starting with dashes it has to be used so that the application can tell the difference between an option and a filename.

   As the classic example, consider what happens if you run `rm *` in a directory containing a file called `-rf`. `rm -- *` prevents the issue (as would `rm ./*`).

Without doing (1) or (2), `ln` indeed sees the string `-r/kernel...` as one of the arguments, and as GNU `ln` reads options from all arguments, not just the first ones, it takes `-r` as a known option, and then errors on `/`, since `-/` is not an option it knows about.

So, in full, what you should do is:

```
kernel_version=$(uname -r)
ln -sf -- "/lib/modules/$kernel_version/extra/mISDN_core.ko" \
    "/lib/modules/$kernel_version/kernel/drivers/isdn/mISDN/mISDN_core.ko"
```